# at sends a BCC to an address that doesn't exist

Tags: linux, email, unix, at

I'm running some pretty long tasks at work and I want to be warned when they finish, wherever I am, so I use `at -m` with sSMTP to get a notification on my Gmail address.

It's my first time playing around with email on Linux, but I managed to set up `/etc/ssmtp/ssmtp.conf` such that, when I use `mail`, it sends the message to and through my Gmail box and, crucially, set up `/etc/mail.rc` so that it doesn't attempt sending a copy to `user@host` since I do not and cannot run an SMTP server on `host`.

I had to add

```
alias user user<account+ssmtp@gmail.com>
```

at the end of `/etc/mail.rc`, otherwise it would send an email to both `account+ssmtp@gmail.com` and `user@host`, with the second bouncing.

When I test this with

```
$ mail user
Subject: This is a test
How does it go?
^DEOT
```

everything goes fine: I received one copy of the message in Gmail and no error message. But when I try to test `at` with

```
$ echo echo test | at -m NOW
warning: commands will be executed using /bin/sh
job 3 at Tue Jun  2 14:12:00 2015
```

I receive the expected message that says "test", but also a second message that says "Delivery to the following recipient failed permanently: user@host".

So, somehow, when `at` sends an email, it looks like it doesn't obey my `alias` directive. How can I fix that?